# control not returning to original vbs file after run command

Tags: vbscript

I am trying to call a vbs file from another. The called file executes. However the control is not returning to the original vbs file. This file appears to be running as I see wscript process in task manager. But i don't see the output - the step after the run command. Any help/suggestion would be appreciated.

1.) vbs file 1 (original vbs file test3.vbs)

```
Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject ("WScript.shell")
strErrorCode  = objShell.run("cmd /K C:\temp\a\test2.vbs", 0, True)
msgbox "complete test3"
Set objShell = Nothing
```

2.) vbs file 2 (called vbs file - test2.vbs)

```
msgbox "in test2"
WScript.Sleep 10000
msgbox "complete - test2"
```

3.) Expected output :

```
in test2
complete - test2
complete test3
```

4.) actual:

```
in test2
complete - test2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`objShell.run("cmd /K C:\temp\a\test2.vbs", 0, True)` never ends due to the `/K` switch:

```
cmd /?
```

> ```
> Starts a new instance of the Windows command interpreter
>
> CMD [/A | /U] [/Q] [/D] [/E:ON | /E:OFF] [/F:ON | /F:OFF] [/V:ON | /V:OFF]
>     [[/S] [/C | /K] string]
>
> /C      Carries out the command specified by string and then terminates
> /K      Carries out the command specified by string but remains
> ```

So `cmd` window remains open but it is hidden owing to the `intWindowStyle` parameter: 0 = *Hides the window and activates another window*, supposing the `Run` method  syntax pattern as `.Run(strCommand, [intWindowStyle], [bWaitOnReturn])`

Use either

```
strErrorCode  = objShell.run("cmd /C C:\temp\a\test2.vbs", 0, True)
```

or

```
strErrorCode  = objShell.run("wscript.exe C:\temp\a\test2.vbs", 0, True)
```

or even

```
 strErrorCode  = objShell.run("C:\temp\a\test2.vbs", 0, True)
```